# CorsFilter losing Representation entity

Tags: cors, restlet

My GET works with the CorsFilter but when I do a file upload post I'm losing the Representation entity at the resource level.  Please help I'm stuck.  The following is the source (/collections GET), (/fileupload POST not working).

```
     CorsFilter corsFilter = new CorsFilter(getContext(), router);
     corsFilter.setAllowedOrigins(new HashSet(Arrays.asList("*")));
     corsFilter.setAllowedCredentials(true);
     corsFilter.setAllowingAllRequestedHeaders(true);
     corsFilter.setSkippingResourceForCorsOptions(true);

     corsFilter.setNext(CollectionsResource.class);
     router.attach("/collections", corsFilter);
     corsFilter.setNext(FileUploadResource.class);
     router.attach("/fileupload", corsFilter);
```

In my Representation entity in the resource my debugger is saying the entity is `[false/*]`.  The Representation is null.

I think it should be something like this: `[multipart/form-data; .....]`.

The following is my HTML & AJAX call Please take a look.  Am I missing something in that?  The get works fine for me but not the POST:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="assetUpload">
<input id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>

$("#assetUpload").submit(function(evt){
evt.preventDefault();

var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    alert("FIRE");
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://localhost:14502/api/v1/fileupload',
 type: 'POST',
 data: formData,
 async: false,
 cache: false,
 contentType: 'false',
 enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
 processData: false,
 success: function (response) {
   alert(response);
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could try to use the `CorsService` instead of the `CorsFilter`. It's more convenient to configure.

Here is the way to configure it on your Restlet application itself:

```
CorsService corsService = new CorsService();
corsService.setAllowedOrigins(new HashSet(Arrays.asList("*")));
corsService.setAllowedCredentials(true);
corsService.setAllowingAllRequestedHeaders(true);
corsService.setSkippingResourceForCorsOptions(true);

application.getServices().add(corsService);
component.getDefaultHost().attachDefault(application);
```

With this approach you don't need anymore to handle the filter when configuring the routing of your application. Here is your refactored code:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public Restlet createInboutRoot() {
        Router router = new Router(getContext());
        router.attach("/collections", CollectionsResource.class);
        router.attach("/fileupload", FileUploadResource.class);
        return router;
    }
}
```

I think that your problem came from the way you defined your routing. In fact, you set twice the next attribute of the `CorsFilter` and the last one wins! So for both paths (`/collections` and `/fileupload`) will be handled by the `FileUploadResource` class.

This blog post could interest you: https://templth.wordpress.com/2014/11/12/understanding-and-using-cors/.

**Edited**

If you want to explicitly use `CorsFilter`, you should refactor your code as described below:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public Restlet createInboutRoot() {
        Router router = new Router(getContext());

        CorsFilter corsFilter = new CorsFilter(getContext(), router);
        corsFilter.setAllowedOrigins(new HashSet(Arrays.asList("*")));
        corsFilter.setAllowedCredentials(true);
        corsFilter.setAllowingAllRequestedHeaders(true);
        corsFilter.setSkippingResourceForCorsOptions(true);

        router.attach("/collections", CollectionsResource.class);
        router.attach("/fileupload", FileUploadResource.class);

        return corsFilter;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: In fact, it's handled for you by Restlet. You define the expected behavior on the service itself. Under the hood, a `CorsFilter` is added within the processing chain for the request. Was it your question?

Comment: Could you please give us some example on how to route through custom filters?  I'm facing issue only during CORS if its the same domain I'm able to upload.

Comment: You can also notice that some work can be necessary on the server side. For example within jQuery or Angular applications... Hope it helps!

Comment: I was wondering if you could take a look at my HTML & AJAX.  The GET is working fine but the POST Representation entity @Post is null still at the Resource level.

Comment: Sure! Feel free to add it to your question!

Comment: Perhaps you could try to add the following within the js object you provide in the `ajax` function: `crossDomain: true,`... Hope it will fix your problem.